# How to connect website to sage 50

Tags: odbc, sage-erp

I have been researching about integrating sage 50 to a website.

The odbc connection is working if I'm on localhost but it's not working on production.

Please confirm what should I check or missing?
I am using PHP to connect it.
It always fails saying Error connecting to the ODBC database: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified